# Archiving an iOS build with previews

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm in the process of archiving an iOS build, but I've encountered an issue related to some shared code that I use in my Previews.

Here's an example below. I have an extension that generates preview data. However, when I attempt to archive the device build, I encounter errors within my previews. It appears that the previews are included in the archive build, but they fail to locate the functions in my extensions, which are wrapped in #if DEBUG macros. I'm not sure why previews would be included in an iOS device archive.

```
#if DEBUG

extension ModelData {
    func previewData() -> String
}

#endif

#Preview {
    let model = ModelData()
    let data = model.previewData()
}
```

Comment: Are your archives being compiled for DEBUG?

Comment: Yes, previews will be part of the archive. The `#Preview` macro generates a struct declaration, and there is nothing special about that struct, so of course it will be included. How about wrapping the previews in `#if DEBUG` too?

Comment: Ok, I just assumed this was already the case. They used to generate these macros automatically but then they got removed when creating a new SwiftUI file in a recent Xcode release.

Comment: Make sure you test your app in release mode. It sounds like you have never done that